# Using promise function inside Javascript Array map

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise

Having an array of objects [obj1, obj2]

I want to use Map function to make a DB query (that uses promises) about all of them and attach the results of the query to each object.

```
[obj1, obj2].map(function(obj){
  db.query('obj1.id').then(function(results){
     obj1.rows = results
     return obj1
  })
})
```

Of course this doesn't work and the output array is [undefined, undefined]

What's the best way of solving a problem like this? I don't mind using other libraries like async

Comment: This question should not have been marked as a duplicate. This question is specifically about using promises inside `map`, _not_ how does async work in general.

Answer (score 208, accepted):

Map your array to promises and then you can use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) function:

```
var promises = [obj1, obj2].map(function(obj){
  return db.query('obj1.id').then(function(results){
     obj1.rows = results
     return obj1
  })
})
Promise.all(promises).then(function(results) {
    console.log(results)
})
```

Comment: how can i match results of promises and data from original model in this case? I want to combine them in starting model

Comment: the order in the arrays is perserved, so you can use array index to match the data and results

Answer (score 22):

Example using async/await:

```
const mappedArray = await Promise.all(
  array.map(p => {
    return getPromise(p).then(i => i.Item);
  })
);
```

Comment: Is await necessary here? I thought `Promise.all` already awaits all promises.

Comment: Promise.all returns a promise that resolves when all promises resolve, otherwise it fails

Answer (score 16):

You are not returning your Promises inside the `map` function.

```
[obj1, obj2].map(function(obj){
  return db.query('obj1.id').then(function(results){
     obj1.rows = results
     return obj1
  })
})
```

Answer (score 9):

You can also do `for await` instead of `map`, and resolve your promises inside of it as well.

Comment: my preferred way to go

Comment: Could you give an example of this?

Comment: `You can also do for await instead of map, and resolve your promises inside of it as well.`

Great! How would I do that?

Answer (score -1):

You can also use [p-map library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/p-map) to handle promises in map function.

> Useful when you need to run promise-returning & async functions multiple times with different inputs concurrently.

> This is different from Promise.all() in that you can control the concurrency and also decide whether or not to stop iterating when there's an error.

Comment: There is also a more generic [iter-ops](https://github.com/vitaly-t/iter-ops) module that has [waitRace](https://vitaly-t.github.io/iter-ops/functions/waitRace) operator to do the same.

Comment: it is not necessary to use library to this task