# sequential queries from database using sequalize in node+express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, sequelize.js

I am just starting node and am from PHP background. I have been trying to figure out promisses for some time now but unable to figure it out.

I am trying to use result of one query in 2nd query in a loop, but having TWO issues:

*-ONE: typeof value shows an object; but when I console it out, it shows undefined*

*-TWO: my results are not getting in the right order. I am trying to use 'then()' but not able to quite figure it out. "inside promise 2" is consoled out before the loop in 'then()' 1 block*

Here's what I'm doing in code:

```
exports.followers_temp = function(req, res)
{
    db.sequelize.query('SELECT DISTINCT public."Users".id as user_id, public."Users".full_name, public."Users".profile_image_url, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM public."Followships" WHERE public."Followships".leader_id = public."Users".id AND public."Followships".follower_id = :leader_id) AS is_followed FROM public."Users"  INNER JOIN public."Followships" ON public."Users".id = public."Followships".follower_id WHERE  public."Followships".leader_id = :leader_id LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset',  { replacements: { leader_id: req.params.leader_id, limit: req.params.limit, offset: req.params.offset }, type: db.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT}).
    then(function(data){
      console.log('i am here; length: ' + data.length);
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
              console.log('inside promise 1, should have access to data object');

              console.log('before loop');
              for(let i=0; i < data.length; i++){
                  var temp = db.sequelize.query('(SELECT COUNT(*) AS is_following FROM public."Followships" WHERE public."Followships".leader_id = ' + data[i].user_id + ' AND public."Followships".follower_id = :my_id)',  { replacements: { leader_id: req.params.leader_id, my_id: req.params.my_id, limit: req.params.limit, offset: req.params.offset }, type: db.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
                  temp.then(function(value){

                    // Issue ONE
                      console.log('type: '+ typeof value); // it's an object
                      console.log('is_following: '+ value.is_following); // yet it's giving undefined

                      console.log('value: '+ JSON.stringify(value)); // but it prints out when I stringify it

                      data[i].is_followed = value.is_following;
                  });
              }
            resolve(data);
            });
    })

    .then(function(my_array){
        // Issue TWO
        console.log('inside promise 2');

        return res.status(200).send({
            error:false,
            message: my_array
        });
    })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log('inside promise catch');
            return res.status(400).send({
                error:true,
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        });
};
```

and here is the console output:

```
i am here; length: 5          
inside promise 1, should have 
before loop                   
inside promise 2              
type: object                  
is_following: undefined       
value: [{"is_following":"1"}] 
type: object                  
is_following: undefined       
value: [{"is_following":"0"}] 
type: object                  
is_following: undefined       
value: [{"is_following":"1"}] 
type: object                  
is_following: undefined       
value: [{"is_following":"1"}] 
type: object                  
is_following: undefined       
value: [{"is_following":"0"}]
```

Please let me know 
-what am I doing wrong?
-if you could working of promises syntax wise... would be great

Thanking you in anticipation; Please ignore rookie mistakes as I am a rookie as of now.

Comment: loops and promises do not mix well. Instead use `Promise.all`

Comment: hmm... Promise.all --- that's a new term for me... i'll look into it's functionality and try to use it if I understood it well. thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching stackoverflow in more depth, I was able to solve my problem. I used help provided on **[THIS POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39452083/using-promise-function-inside-javascript-array-map)**.

I thank stackoverflow community for all the help. I will try to contribute as well in future.

Final solution looks like this:

```
    exports.followers_temp = function (req, res) {
    db.sequelize.query('SELECT DISTINCT public."Users".id as user_id, public."Users".full_name, public."Users".profile_image_url, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM public."Followships" WHERE public."Followships".leader_id = public."Users".id AND public."Followships".follower_id = :leader_id) AS is_followed FROM public."Users"  INNER JOIN public."Followships" ON public."Users".id = public."Followships".follower_id WHERE  public."Followships".leader_id = :leader_id LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset', { replacements: { leader_id: req.params.leader_id, limit: req.params.limit, offset: req.params.offset }, type: db.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT })
        .then(function (users) {
            var promises = users.map(function(user){
                return db.sequelize.query(
                    '(SELECT COUNT(*) AS is_following FROM public."Followships" WHERE public."Followships".leader_id = ' +
                    user.user_id + ' AND public."Followships".follower_id = :my_id)',
                    { replacements:
                            { leader_id: req.params.leader_id,
                                my_id: req.params.my_id,
                                limit: req.params.limit,
                                offset: req.params.offset
                            },
                        type: db.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
                    })
                    .then(function(results){
                        user.is_followed = results[0].is_following;
                        return user
                    })
            })
            Promise.all(promises).then(function(results) {
                return res.status(200).send({
                    error: false,
                    message: users
                });
            })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    return res.status(400).send({
                        error: true,
                        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
                    });
                });
        })
    .catch(function (err) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            error: true,
            message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`db.sequelize.query` is an asynchronous call put in a `for` loop. This will start queries but have not successfully completed yet. So, your `data` is not complete yet and you are resolving it already. With `Promise.all` you can write it as follows:

```
Promise.all(data.map((val) => { // here val = data[i] inside the query
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.sequelize.query(...)
            .then((value) => {
                // modify your data object here.
                resolve();
            });
    });
})).then(() => { resolve(data);});
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use `new Promise` if you already have a promise:

```
exports.followers_temp = function (req, res) {
  db.sequelize.query('SELECT DISTINCT public."Users".id as user_id, public."Users".full_name, public."Users".profile_image_url, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM public."Followships" WHERE public."Followships".leader_id = public."Users".id AND public."Followships".follower_id = :leader_id) AS is_followed FROM public."Users"  INNER JOIN public."Followships" ON public."Users".id = public."Followships".follower_id WHERE  public."Followships".leader_id = :leader_id LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset', { replacements: { leader_id: req.params.leader_id, limit: req.params.limit, offset: req.params.offset }, type: db.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT })
  .then(function (users) {
    console.log('i am here; length: ' + users.length);
    //do not use new Promise if you already have a promie
    //https://stackoverflow.com/a/48576246/1641941
    //use promise.all and map data to promises
    return Promise.all(
      users.map(
        user=>{
          db.sequelize.query(
            '(SELECT COUNT(*) AS is_following FROM public."Followships" WHERE public."Followships".leader_id = :leader_id AND public."Followships".follower_id = :my_id)', 
            { replacements: 
              { leader_id: user.user_id,//changed leader_id
                my_id: req.params.my_id//removed limit and offset 
              },
              type: db.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT 
            })
            .then(function (value) {
              console.log('type: ' + typeof value);
              //value is an array
              console.log('is_following: ' + value[0].is_following);
              console.log('value: ' + JSON.stringify(value));    
              user.is_followed = value[0].is_following;
              return user;
            });
        }
      )
    )
  })
  .then(function (users) {
    // Issue TWO
    console.log('inside promise 2',users);
    return res.status(200).send({
      error: false,
      message: users
    });
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log('inside promise catch',err);
    return res.status(400).send({
      error: true,
      message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the help... I see a good coding style,wil follow it but your code is still printing "inside promise 2" before printing other data i.e: "i am here; length: 5
    inside promise 2 [ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ]
    type: object
    is_following: 0
    value: [{"is_following":"0"}]
    type: object
    is_following: 0
    value: [{"is_following":"0"}]
    type: object
    is_following: 0
    value: [{"is_following":"0"}]
...   and how did you know it was an array while typeof is showing object?

Comment: I think you made a mistake in the second query where you replace leader_id with request.params.leader_id, will update the anser. I know it's an object because array is object (typeof [] is "object")your question shows it is: `value: [{"is_following":"1"}] ` an object is `{}` an array is `[]` an object in an array is: `[{}]`

Comment: o yes, array is an object in javascript...  in second query leader_id is not even used, it's redundant. I removed last then() and tried to send response at the end of promise.all but it says 'header already sent'... maybe because of the loop. I am still trying to fix it and will post here when fixed...