# React: how to wait for map function to complete before updating state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, async-await

I have an array of ids, stored in `ids`, that I'm mapping over an async function, `asyncFunc`. I want to store the result of the mapping into `newArr` and then update state via `setState`. Here's my code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const newArr = [];
    ids.map((element) => {
      asyncFunc(variables).then((data) => {
        newArr.push({ layer: makeLayer(data) });
      });
    });
    setState([...layers, ...newArr]);
  }, [variables]);
```

My issue is that the state is updating before the mapping completes. **How can I use `.then()` to update the state only when data from all the mappings were returned?** Wrapping `ids.map` with `Promise.all` didn't work. In addition, the following returns an error:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const newArr = [];
    (ids.map((element) => {
      asyncFunc(variables).then((data) => {
        newArr.push({ layer: makeLayer(data) });
      });
    })).then(()=> {
       setState([...layers, ...newArr]);    
    })
  }, [variables]);
```

Comment: What about using `Promise.all`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using promise function inside Javascript Array map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39452083/using-promise-function-inside-javascript-array-map)

Comment: Wrapping the map into Promise.all would have probably worked if your map did actually return anything, you are missing return statement inside map

Comment: @evolutionxbox he said he tried it already—but I would be interested to see a snippet of how you tried it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare a async function to populate the array and return your array within a `Promise.all`. Something like this should work for what you're trying to accomplish:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const populateArray = async () => {
      const newArr = await Promise.all(ids.map(async element => {
        const data = await asyncFunc(variables)

        return { layer: makeLayer(data) }
      })

      setState([...layers, ...newArr]);
    }

    populateArray()
  }, [variables]);
```

Comment: elegant solution and worked like a charm. Thanks!